# Обработка ошибок http Get

Tags: golang

Добрый день.

Подскажите как обработать ошибку.

```
Get http://www.********/: http: error connecting to proxy http://14.134.103.201:808: dial tcp 14.134.103.201:808: i/o timeout
```

Вот мой код.

```
<pre>   proxyUrl, err := url.Parse("http://14.134.103.201:808")
if err != nil {
        log.Println("proxyUrl")
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    tr := &http.Transport{
        Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyUrl),
        Dial: (&net.Dialer{
            Timeout:   30 * time.Second,
            KeepAlive: 30 * time.Second,
        }).Dial,
    }

    clinetHttp := &http.Client{
        //Timeout: 50 * time.Second,
        Transport: tr,
    }

    res, err := clinetHttp.Get(urls)

    if err != nil{
        log.Println("Get urls")
        log.Println(err)
        return doc, statuscode, err
    }

    defer res.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("close")
    }
    // Convert the designated charset HTML to utf-8 encoded HTML.
    // `charset` being one of the charsets known by the iconv package.
    utfBody, err := iconv.NewReader(res.Body, "windows-1251", "utf-8")
    CheckErr(err)
    // use utfBody using goquery
    doc, err = goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(utfBody)
    CheckErr(err)
    statuscode = res.StatusCode

    return doc, statuscode, err </pre>
```

Comment: Что значит "обработать ошибку"? В каком именно месте кода у вас возникает ошибка и что вы хотите с ней делать?

Comment: Если прокси сервер недоступен в этом месте появляется ошибка `res, err := clinetHttp.Get(urls)` как проверить что именно эта ошибка (dial tcp 14.134.103.201:808: i/o timeout) ? ну и собственно если это она то сделать какое то действие...

Comment: Бывает еще `Get http://www.*****: http: error connecting to proxy http://124.119.92.103:8998: dial tcp 124.119.92.103:8998: getsockopt: connection refused`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибки, возвращаемые в `net/http` - это [`*url.Error`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Error). Пример инспекции ошибки:

```
resp, err := c.Get("http://localhost:4000")
if err != nil {
    switch err := err.(type) {
    case *url.Error:
        if err.Timeout() {
            log.Printf("timeout: %s", err.Err)
        } else if err, ok := err.Err.(*net.OpError); ok {
            log.Printf("net error: %s", err)
        } else {
            log.Printf("original error: %T", err.Err)
        }
    default:
        log.Printf("unknown error: %v", err)
    }
}
```

Ниже находится старый ответ, неверный.

---

Увы, не нахожу, где бы пакет `net/http` выставил эти ошибки наружу. Похоже, вам придётся обойтись чем-то костыльным вроде

```
func isProxyError(err error) bool {
    return strings.Contains(err.Error(), "error connecting to proxy")
}
```

Возможно, стоит завести тикет, чтобы разработчики опубликовали типы ошибок в `net/http` с возможностью узнать изначальную ошибку.

Comment: Да действительно решения нет, либо RegEx. Короче костыль.

Comment: @СергейАндрианов Обновил ответ. Если приведёте к `*url.Error`, можете изъять ошибку.